# How to have a default /api route?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using the latest Asp.Net Core 3 template in Visual Studio.

There is the default `HomeController`, which is mapped via `/Home`, and also its `Index` action is reached via `/`.

I added two Api controllers: `DefaultController` and `MController`, child class of `ControllerBase`. These are mapped via `/api/default` and `/api/m` automatically. I can't find where the routing is configured.

What must I do to achieve the following routes:

```
/      -> /HomeController/Index (no change)
/home  -> /HomeController (no change)
/api   -> /api/default
/api/m -> /api/m (no change)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default template will have the Route Annotation referencing the controllers name i.e.

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
```

Try changing it to:

```
[Route("api")]
class DefaultController 
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your launchSettings.json to do that

```
"profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/value", // here
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
```

or Right click your web project -> Select Properties -> Select the Debug tab on the left -> Then edit the 'Launch Url' field to set your own default launch url.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding an extra `[Route("api")]` will make it.

For example:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api", Name="DefaultAPI")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class DefaultController : Controller
{
    ...

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return Ok("abc");
    }

    ...
}
```

The following request will be routed to `DefaultController/Index`

```
GET https://localhost:5001/api
GET https://localhost:5001/api/Default
```